# How to get rows with highest value, if two or more Columns have same value

Tags: php, mysql

I have posts table, i want to display most viewed posts first, but i am not getting proper result if two or more columns have same value. I mean if one posts have 25 views and second have the same(25) views, then i am getting only one result, but i want to display all the results. Help me please..

Here is My Code :

```
$real_query = mysqli_query(
  $connect,
  "SELECT id, note_topic, note_owner_id, note_by_name, 
   views FROM user_note GROUP BY views ORDER BY MAX(views) DESC"
);
```

Comment: from user_note order by views desc? - otherwise, your question is very unclear

Answer (score 1):

Just remove grouping by views:

```
GROUP BY views
```

Also remove aggregation from ORDER BY clause:

```
ORDER BY MAX(views) DESC
```

to

```
ORDER BY views DESC
```

Comment: then i am getting only one result

Comment: Remove MAX() from ORDER BY clause

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a query like this one:

```
select
  id, note_topic, note_owner_id, note_by_name, views
from
  user_note
where
  views = (select MAX(views) from user_note)
```

if there's only one maximum post, this query will just return 1 row, otherwise it will return all rows that have the maximum number of views.

Comment: As a note:  this should be very efficient with an index on `user_note(views)`.

Comment: This will show the post with the most number of views, or more posts if there is a tie. It won't select the post on 2nd place, 3rd and so on.

Comment: i am getting only one result

Comment: @ShubhamTripathi what if you try `select .. from user_note order by views desc` ?

Comment: @fthiella ooh ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will display the top ten records ordered by the number of views, in descendant order,
including records that have the same number of top views

```
SELECT 
    id, note_topic, note_owner_id, note_by_name, views 
FROM 
    user_note 
ORDER BY views DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: how many results do you have in the database? can you show a sample from your table ordered by `views`?

Comment: ooh sorry bro, it was my mistake sorry